# Determine if all the phrases are found within the input string

Tags: python

What am i doing wrong in the code

## Objective of the code is to

Determine if all the phrases are found within the input string.

If they're all found (using distance as a measure of leeway) return True. Else False.
Example:

- input = 'can i go to the bathroom in the morning',
- phrases = ['can go', 'bathroom morning']
- if distance is 1 then this won't result in a match because
  'bathroom', 'morning' has 2 words between it
- if distance is 2 then 'bathroom in the morning' is counted as a valid phrase

### Expected Output

```
    input = "can i go to the bathroom in the morning"
    phrases = ['can go', 'bathroom morning']
    distance = 2 
    print('Output',get_compound_keyword_match(input, phrases, distance))
```

`Output True`

My Code:

```
def get_compound_keyword_match(input: str, phrases: list, distance: int) -> bool:
  
   if not distance:
       # We have no leeway for a match.
       if all(phrase in input for phrase in phrases):
           return True

   keywords = input.split()
   for phrase in phrases:
       phrase_matched = False
       ck_words = phrase.split()
       first_word_matches = [
           i for i, x in enumerate(keywords) if x == ck_words[0]
       ]
       print('first word matches', first_word_matches)
       if not first_word_matches:
           return False

       for first_word_match in first_word_matches:
           old_match_index = first_word_match
           matched = False
           for i in range(0, len(ck_words)):
               try:
                   match_index = keywords.index(ck_words[i])
                   if match_index - old_match_index > (distance + 1):
                       matched = False
                   old_match_index = match_index
               except ValueError:
                   print('value error false')
                   matched = False
           if matched:
               phrase_matched = True
               break

       if not phrase_matched:
           print('phrase_matched false')
           return False
   return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = "can i go to the bathroom in the morning"
    phrases = ['can go', 'bathroom morning']
    distance = 2 
    print('Output',get_compound_keyword_match(input, phrases, distance))
```

Comment: You have the expected output, but what is the current output from your code?

Comment: [Reposting closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057246/improve-the-following-python-code-that-checks-the-valid-phrases-in-input-string) is not very welcomed here

Comment: @user56700 Current output is Output False

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_compound_keyword_match(text: str, phrases: list, distance: int) -> bool:
    if not distance:
        return all(phrase in text for phrase in phrases)

    keywords = text.split()

    for phrase in phrases:
        words = phrase.split()

        kw_prev_index = -1

        for word in words:
            if not word in keywords:
                return False
    
            kw_index = keywords.index()

            if kw_index == -1:
                return False

            if kw_prev_index != -1 and kw_index - kw_prev_index - 1 > distance:
                return False

            kw_prev_index = kw_index

    return True
```